# Have trouble with a while loop and trying to terminate the program by a press of a letter

Tags: java

I have a problem with my program.

Program is a **HILO** game which requires the user to guess a number between a range of a generated number.

The problem is that once i press 0 on my keyboard, it reveals the random number, and essentially must end the loop and ask whether the user wants to continue or end the program. Instead, it continues the loop, and whenever I press a letter on the keyboard it shows me an `Exception` error which describes and input Miss Match. Can some one guide me on how to fix it?, maybe I wrote the program wrong, I tried multiple ways, it still doesn't work as it supposed to work.
Thank you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.Math;

public class HILOGAME
{
    public static void firstGame()
    {
        final int range = 50;
        int answer = 0;
        int guesses;
        int number;
        int guessNum = 0;

        String choice = "";
        boolean Loop = false;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();

        answer = r.nextInt(range) + 1;

        System.out.println("IF YOU WISH TO GIVE UP, PRESS 0 ON THE KEYBOARD");

        while (!Loop)
        {
            for (int exit = 0; exit < 10; exit++)
            {
                System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and " + range + " : ");
                number = input.nextInt();
                guessNum = guessNum++;
                guessNum += 1;

                if (number == answer)
                {
                    System.out.println(" Your guess was correct ");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("The number was: " + answer);
                    System.out.println("You guess the number with: " + guessNum + " guesses ");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Enter x to continue to play or y to endgame");
                    choice = input.nextLine();

                    if (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
                    {
                        Loop = true;
                        answer = r.nextInt(range) + 1;
                        System.out.print("A new number");
                        break;
                    }

                    else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                    {
                        Loop = false;
                        System.out.print("END OF GAME");
                        exit = 11;
                    }
                }

                if (number > answer)
                {
                    System.out.println("TOO HIGH");
                }
                if (number < answer)
                {
                    System.out.println("TOO LOW");
                }

                if (number == 0)
                {
                    System.out.println("YOU GAVE UP. THE NUMBER WAS " + answer);
                    System.out.println("Enter x to continue to play or y to endgame");
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see my answer below @ALEXSW..!!

Comment: @ALEXSW you program seems fine except the use of scanner class. Whenever you read a numerical value using scanner, you should also remove the new line in the buffer using input.nextLine(). You input a numerical value in the console and press enter. nextInt() will only read the numerical value and not the enter that you pressd. So remove the enter from buffer by .nextLine() after reading a numerical value. This is not required while reading strings since, new line also will be read by the .nextLine() method.

Comment: check my answer now

Comment: Well, I copied your answer, and its not ending the program, it continues to loop and then if I press again y, it shows the exception error again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1:**

**This code is working perfectly for me i have tried running it:**

```
final int range = 50;
    int answer = 0;
    int guesses;
    int number;
    int guessNum = 0;

    String choice = "";
    boolean Loop = false;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random r = new Random();

    answer = r.nextInt(range) + 1;

    System.out.println("IF YOU WISH TO GIVE UP, PRESS 0 ON THE KEYBOARD");

    while (!Loop)
    {
        int exit;
        for (exit = 0; exit < 10; exit++)
        {
            System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and " + range + " : ");
            number = input.nextInt();
            guessNum = guessNum++;
            guessNum += 1;

            if (number == answer)
            {
                System.out.println(" Your guess was correct ");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("The number was: " + answer);
                System.out.println("You guess the number with: " + guessNum + " guesses ");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("Enter x to continue to play or y to endgame");
                choice = input.next();

                // HERE YOU ARE DOING THE WRONG THING
                // What is the meaning of "not(!)" here ? !choice.equalsIgnoreCase("x")
                // Remove "NOT(!)" from here your program will work as expected

                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
                {
                    //here you should assign loop to false if they continue
                    Loop = false;
                    answer = r.nextInt(range) + 1;
                    System.out.print("A new number");
                    break;
                }
                else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                {
                    //better to insert break here as well
                    //here you should assign loop to true if they wanna exit.
                    Loop = true;
                    System.out.print("END OF GAME");
                    exit = 11;
                    break;
                }
            }

            else if (number > answer)
            {
                System.out.println("TOO HIGH");
            }
            else if (number < answer)
            {
                System.out.println("TOO LOW");
            }

            if (number == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("YOU GAVE UP. THE NUMBER WAS " + answer);
                System.out.println("Enter x to continue to play or y to endgame");

                // MADE CHANGES HERE

                choice = input.next();

                if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("x"))
                {
                    //here you should assign loop to false if they continue
                    Loop = false;
                    answer = r.nextInt(range) + 1;
                    System.out.print("A new number");
                    break;
                }
                else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"))
                {
                    //better to insert break here as well
                    //here you should assign loop to true if they wanna exit.
                    Loop = true;
                    System.out.print("END OF GAME");
                    exit = 11;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Please do copy-paste the code. Because it is working perfectly without any Exception..!!

My sample outputs:

**SAMPLE 1:**

```
Guess a number between 1 and 50 : 1
TOO LOW
Guess a number between 1 and 50 : 0
TOO LOW
YOU GAVE UP. THE NUMBER WAS 27
Enter x to continue to play or y to endgame
y
END OF GAME
```

**SAMPLE 2:**

```
Guess a number between 1 and 50 : 20
TOO HIGH
Guess a number between 1 and 50 : 19
TOO HIGH
Guess a number between 1 and 50 : 15
 Your guess was correct 

The number was: 15
You guess the number with: 3 guesses 

Enter x to continue to play or y to endgame
x
A new numberGuess a number between 1 and 50 : 20
TOO LOW
Guess a number between 1 and 50 : 0
TOO LOW
YOU GAVE UP. THE NUMBER WAS 42
Enter x to continue to play or y to endgame
y
END OF GAME
```

Do let me know if there is any problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you wish to end a loop, you could use the `break;` command. It jumps out of a `while` or `for` loop. So you could use this if the number is 0:

```
if (number == 0)
{
  System.out.println("YOU GAVE UP. THE NUMBER WAS " + answer);
  System.out.println("Enter 'x' to continue to play or y to endgame");
  choice = input.nextLine();
  if(choice == "y")
  {
    break;
  }
```

and add:
`if(choice == "y") {break;}` to the very end of the `while(!Loop)` loop.

And with the time when the answer is correct, you set `Loop` to false, which means `!Loop` would evaluate to true. You should change `Loop = false` to `Loop = true` when they decide to continue the game.

Comment: You mean, I need to put Loop == true if the answer is correct?

Comment: No you assigned `Loop` to false when they chose to quit the game, and that meant that `while(!Loop)` would still continue. You should set `Loop` to false when they choose to continue, not quit. I would suggest you listen to janki gadhiya's answer, as it is much more complete and comprehensive than mine.

Comment: For his answer, you should have a `main` function as well, just call `firstGame()` from within it. Seems as though it would work to me though, but you're the judge here.

Answer (score 0):

a small modification

```
public class HILOGAME {
    public static void firstGame() {
        final int range = 50;
        int answer;
        int number;
        int guessNum = 0;

        String choice = "";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random r = new Random();

        answer = r.nextInt(range) + 1;

        System.out.print("Guess a number between 1 and " + range + " : ");
        number = input.nextInt();
        if (number == answer) {
            System.out.println(" Your guess was correct ");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("The number was: " + answer);
            System.out.println("You guess the number with: " + guessNum + " guesses ");
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            System.out.println("you entered a wrong value");
            System.out.println("do you really want to try again? press y to continue or other alphabet to exit");
            choice = input.next();
            playAgain(choice);
        }

    }

    public static void playAgain(String choice) {
        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
            firstGame();
        } else {
            System.out.println("you chose to quit");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: if user presses `y` you want to end the program and if he presses rest of alphabet you want to start the loop again??

Comment: The problem is that it doesnt end the loop, it continues, and if i press y or x it shows me an exception error.

Comment: why u iterating `for (int exit = 0; exit < 10; exit++)` ??

Comment: I tried to make like a limit with the loop, so that if exit = 11 , it will end the loop.

Comment: Cannot chat, not reputation 6 yet

Comment: wait let me check it